# Range of mat-paginator sets back to its initial value when list is rendered

Tags: html, angular, pagination

I am implementing pagination with the help of a backend API using an angular material paginator. The range of the paginator updates when the next button is clicked but as soon as the list is rendered the range shows 1-10 again. Here's my code:

```
getNext(event: PageEvent) {
        this.applicationService.getNextApplications(event).subscribe((applications: PaginationModel) => {
            this.dataSource.data = applications.data;
            this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.sort((a, b) => a.appName.localeCompare(b.appName));
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.dataSource.paginator.length = applications.totalCount;
                this.limit = event.pageSize;
            });
            this.isDataReceivedByServer = true;
        });
    }
```

The above method calls the api and gets the paginated values

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        });
    }
```

```
<mat-paginator [length]="totalLength" [pageSize]="limit" [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 25,50, 100]"
    (page)="getNext($event)">
  </mat-paginator>
```

I am not getting why the pagination is not working fine and the values gets set to its initial values.

Comment: Can you provide a minimum of reproductible code, for example in a StackBlitz ? From what I see you need to use `async` pipe on dataSource after having initialized the variable with the right Observable. I can't be formal about it without reproductible code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataSource was setting the pageIndex of the paginator to 0. So I had to get the current page and bind it to the pageIndex property of dataSource.paginator like this in the setTimeOut function.
 `getNext(event: PageEvent) {
        this.userService.getNextUsers(event).subscribe(users => {
            this.dataSource.data = users.data;
            this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.sort((a, b) =>a.firstName.localeCompare(b.firstName));
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.dataSource.paginator.length = users.totalCount;
                this.dataSource.paginator.pageIndex = users.currentPage - 1;
                this.limit = event.pageSize;
            });
            this.isDataReceivedByServer = true;
        });
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly update `MatPaginator.pageIndex`. Not sure of what `this.dataSource` in your example is made of. Maybe you can use `this.dataSource.paginator.pageIndex`, otherwise try to obtain a reference to the `MatPaginator` using `@ViewChild` first.

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;

getNext(event: PageEvent) {
    ...
    this.paginator.pageIndex += 1;
    ...        
}
```

Comment: `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ApplicationModel>();`
dataSource is being used to store the response from API to show in the mat table. I have already used the `@ViewChild` line. Actually the problem is that the range gets updated on clicking the next button but as soon as the list gets rendered, the range again goes to initial value.